# php routing how to handle query parameters?

Tags: php, url-routing

I have a router class in my php project that works like this:

```
public function dispatch(){
     foreach ($this->routes as $url => $action) {

        if( $url == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ){

            if(is_callable($action)) return $action();

            $actionArr = explode('#', $action);
            $controller = 'My\\system\\controllers\\'.$actionArr[0];
            $method = $actionArr[1];

            return (new $controller)->$method();
        }
    }
}
```

And I define the routes like this:

```
My\system\classes\Registry::get("Router")->add('/My/admin/','AdminController#index');
```

So when the URL `SERVER/My/admin` is called the `index` method of the `AdminController` class is called.

**My problem: How do I handle query strings?**

I'd like to have a page with a form. On submit, the form gets sent to `SERVER/My/admin/check`, i.e. to the `check.php` page in the `admin` folder.

I defined the route like this

```
My\system\classes\Registry::get("Router")->add('/My/admin/check','AdminController#check');
```

but the URL isn't found, of course, because the query string is attatched to the URL. How should I handle this best?

Comment: What's your `htaccess` look like? A lot of router implementations will pass the route (url) into a query parameter meaning you don't need to account for other query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Before checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, remove everything past the first `?`, if one is present. Use that value to check if it matches with `$url`. Something as simple as this will do the trick:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if( ($pos = strpos($request, '?')) !== false) $request = substr($request, 0, $pos);
```

Any controllers that need to work with query parameters should be able to get them from `$_GET`, or at worst `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 0):

This example is from my project, how I handle this.

**REQUEST_URI** - The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

```
$full_router = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

**strtok()** splits a string (string) into smaller strings (tokens), with each token being delimited by any character from token.

```
$router = strtok($full_router, '?'); // This is how you can handle query parameters
```

Now you can match the URL with if statement

```
if($router === '/' ){
    include('/pages/home.php');
}
```